SvelteKit is not storing cookies when doing a request inside of the `load` function
In my SvelteKit site I do a request to my backend inside of the LayoutServerLoad function, in +layout.server.ts. Namely when the site is opened with an ?affiliate_id=bla query parameter, I want to send this to the backend:
import type { LayoutServerLoad } from "./$types";
import { keyBy } from "$lib/utils";
import { backendUrl } from "$lib/config";

export const trailingSlash = "always";

export const load: LayoutServerLoad = async ({ locals, url, fetch }) => {
  const affiliate_id = url.searchParams.get("affiliate_id");
  if (affiliate_id) {
    const headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "X-CSRFToken": locals.csrfToken,
    };

    fetch(`${backendUrl}/shop/basket/`, { method: "POST", credentials: "include", headers, body: JSON.stringify({ affiliate_id }) })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error("Error storing affiliate_id: ", error);
      });
  }

  return {
    // I'm returning a bunch of data here
  };
};

The problem is that the backend response contains a set-cookie header and the cookie is not getting stored in the browser.
When I change my load function to just return the affiliate_id:
export const load: LayoutServerLoad = async ({ locals, url }) => {
  return {
    affiliateId: url.searchParams.get("affiliate_id"),
    // and more data
  };
};

And then make the request inside of +layout.svelte, then it all works fine.
<script lang="ts">
  import type { PageData } from "./$types";
  import { onMount } from "svelte";

  export let data: PageData;
  const { affiliateId } = data;

  onMount(async () => {
    if (affiliateId) {
      // Do the request here
    }
  });
</script>

<slot />

Now the cookie from the response is stored in the browser just fine.
Why is the cookie not stored when doing the same request in the load function?

Requests in a server load function are made by the server not the client's browser; the client will not receive any cookies by default (though there is some logic that forwards cookies when making the request).
The server load function event object has a cookies property, which could be used to forward cookies. This may be a bit roundabout since the returned header has to be parsed first (you get an error when trying to set a Set-Cookie header directly).

I thought that while the request is indeed initially made from the server, that it'll pass the headers then on to the client so that cookies can be stored. Is this not correct? Or should I just move the logic to +layout.ts?

That is not correct, as I said, the cookies are not forwarded, it would be a security issue. Imagine authenticating against some API using a private key and the session token is exposed directly to any client. Whether the logic can/should be moved to a universal load function or the page also depends on whether the request can directly happen on the client.

In the end I moved the logic to +layout.ts, wrapped within an if (browser) { check (because I don't want this code to run twice, first in SSR and then on the client). Seems cleaner than having to involve +layout.server.ts and +layout.svelte, keep all the logic in one file.
